# Cannot load a component library in the application created with create-sigle-spa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have a component library made in React and i use Rollup to build the library.

I created a test application using 'create-single-spa' with Typescript.

When I import my component library into the application the following error happens:

> Uncaught Error: application '@org/test' died in status
> LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Error loading http://localhost:8500/org-test.js
> (SystemJS Error#3 https://git.io/JvFET#3) at
> HTMLScriptElement. (system.js:640)

[image]

The import test done on the root file: 
[image]

Testing using an application created with 'create-react-app' the library import normally works.